# Retrieve Key and Value From Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database structure as shown. I am able to fetch value of key. But I want both key and value say displayed in Recyclerview.

```
 "itemprice" : {
"-KJWAtjsgvjqaa9Xnb1R" : {
  "half" : "100",
  "one" : "200"
},
"-KJWBAihYrjaH5zJe62i" : {
  "half" : "50",
  "one" : "200"
}
```

Now I want to retrieve and show both key and its value (For example I want half and 100 to be retrieved. Also one and 200). How can I show it in my activity?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for reading the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

retrive data once:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Map<String, Integer> itemPrice = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
        int helf = itemPrice.get("helf");
        int one = itemPrice.get("one");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

with on change listener:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Map<String, Integer> itemPrice = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            int helf = itemPrice.get("helf");
            int one = itemPrice.get("one");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```